# Are there any documents about access modifiers in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm looking for documents about access modifiers in Kotlin.
But its unfound.

I want to know and check access modifier for package function and difference protected modifier in Kotlin and in Java.

[edited]
I'm looking for public document by Jetbrians.

I found thread about access modifier.
http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/451236?tstart=0

Comment: Curious that you found nothing when Google gives me 558,000 results.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for your comment. Sorry, my question is not good.  I'm looking for public document by Jetbrians.

Comment: Keep looking. Requests like that are off-topic here.

Comment: @EJP Oh really?
I read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

I think that it doesn't forbid directly to ask about document like this.
But my question is not good question.
I will not ask like this question again. 

Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html

> Classes, objects, traits, constructors, functions, properties and their setters can have visibility modifiers. (Getters always have the same visibility as the property.) There are four visibility modifiers in Kotlin:
>
> **private** — visible only in the declaring scope and its subscopes (inside the same module);
>
> **protected** — (applicable only to class/trait
> members) like private, but also visible in subclasses;
>
> **internal** —
> visible everywhere within the same module (if the
> owner of declaring scope is visible);
>
> **public** —  (used by default) visible everywhere (if
> the owner of declaring scope is visible).
>
> NOTE: Functions with expression bodies and all properties declared
> public must always specify return types explicitly. This is required
> so that one has no chance of accidentally changing a type that is a
> part of a public API by merely altering the implementation.